# How do I modify a field on a collection of objects I pass in

Tags: c#, foreach, mutable, ref

I am trying to do the following... (Foo is a class)

```
void Main() 
{
    var foos = ...
    DoSomeWork(foos);
    // I want all foos to have Bar set to 42
}

public static void DoSomeWork(IEnumberable<Foo> foos) 
{
    foreach (var foo in foos)
    {
        foo.Bar = 42;
    }
}

class Foo 
{
    String blahblah;
    Int32 Bar;
}
```

But all the foos have their original values. How do I change them on a ref parameter?

Comment: `ref` is not needed for the collection (`foos`).

Comment: Do these `foo`s come from a database query by any chance?

Comment: @Gabe No they come from LINQ to XML

Comment: Is Bar a property or a public member? If its a property then what is your setter implementation?

Comment: it's a public `Int32` field (I said `Boolean` before because that's what it really is in my code and I am tired)

Comment: Did you call ToList method against your LINQ query? Take into attention a deferred execution nature of LINQ queries.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: Was just thinking that, that `foos` might be a generating `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy post that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that `foos` is a generating `IEnumerable`. Example:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
  yield return new Foo {};
  yield return new Foo {};
  yield return new Foo {};
}

var foos = GetFoos();
```

You can never mutate the values being generated, as they will be freshly created each time you iterate over `foos`.

Now if you did the following as suggested by @YuriyRozhovetskiy, it will work.

```
var foos = GetFoos().ToList();
```

Now we can mutate happily :)

Comment: +1.  this is one of those things about an `IEnumerable` that you never think about until its bites you once or twice.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't force LINQ query execution with methods like `ToList` or `ToArray`, each time you enumerate  over the query it have executed all over again. You need to cache query results with the `ToList` method and then pass that list to the `DoSomeWork` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, it should work for reference type (class) and it would not compile for value type (struct).

First of all, you don't need to pass ref IEnumerable to DoSomeWork, because you don't want to change the collection object, only modify elements inside.

I tried to reproduce your case, but it works OK, code below. Could you give some more details?

- What collection you are passing (List, Set)?
- If Bar is property - how it's implemented?
- Is Foo a reference type (class)?

Working code:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int bar, int baz)
    {
        Bar = bar;
        Baz = baz;
    }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>(new[]
        {
            new Foo(1, 2),
            new Foo(3, 4),
            new Foo(5, 6)
        });
        DoSomeWork(foos);
    }

    private static void DoSomeWork(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            foo.Bar = 42;
            foo.Baz = 42;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You make too many assumptions why it should work, but no suggestions why it will not work.